# How i convert wave file to it's equivalent data array in c#

Tags: c#

I want to convert my recorded audio (that is saved in .wav file) to double array.in Matlab we use [data,fs] = audioread('filename.wav'); to extract or convert wave file to data array then how i get same data in c#.

Answer (score 3):

Use `File.ReadAllBytes()` like

```
byte[] audio = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path_of_your_wav_file);
```

Comment: Just as a general note: If OP only wants the actual audio data (which is what the matlab function returns) he will have to trim the [wav header](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) after reading it this way.